# poi has a implicitly max row number

Tags: apache-poi

I used `poi` 3.12 to create excel, and found a phenomenon, that is explicitly created 30000 rows, but open the generated excel, only have 27239 rows, and there is no error output. So it seems poi have set a default max row number--27239. But I tried track source code, cannot find some variable like max rows. The code is

```
InputStream is = new FileInputStream(srcFile);
POIFSFileSystem pOIFSFileSystem=new POIFSFileSystem(is); 
HSSFWorkbook srcWorkbook = new HSSFWorkbook(pOIFSFileSystem);
buildBusiData(srcWorkbook);
FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(desFile);
srcWorkbook.write(fileOutputStream);

fileOutputStream.flush();
fileOutputStream.close();
```

So how is this?

Comment: Excel `.xls` files are limited to [64k (2^16) rows](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/SpreadsheetVersion.html#EXCEL97), that's the only limit POI enforces and that's a file format one. So, any bugs must be in your code, and without being able to see the generation code there's nothing we can do to help...

Comment: Thanks @Gagravarr you are right. I have found the reason, please see my post below. But it is not very easy to find it, at first I thought the cause must in `HSSFWorkbook.write` and tracked it, but found nothing. Then I put `HSSFSheet.getLastRowNum()` in diff place and locate the problem code finally.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the reason, that is the source file(template) only have 27239 rows

```
#source file
cat coupon_code_box.csv | wc -l
27240
# 
head coupon_code_box.csv -n 3
table header here
" "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "
" "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "
```

and in my code does not create new row explicitly, so if row number greater than 27239, it'll ignore it.

```
Row row = sheet.getRow(rowIndex);
if(row!=null){
    Cell cell = row.getCell(celIndex);
    cell.setCellValue(fillVal);
}
```

Now my solution is

```
Row row = sheet.getRow(rowIndex);
if(row==null){
    row=sheet.createRow(rowIndex); //explicitly create one new row
}
if(row!=null){
    Cell cell = row.getCell(celIndex);
    if(cell==null)
        cell = row.createCell(celIndex); //explicitly create one new cell
    cell.setCellValue(fillVal);
}
```

Comment: Not sure that last code is all needed - you ensure a cell is never null then check it isn't null?